# Filter entire sections of UITableView according to section header

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out the best way to approach this. I have a UITableView, and within it there could be X number of sections. I also have a button that produces a popover with a custom UIPickerView that displays the titles of each section (I got those values from the array, not the UITableView since I couldn't figure out how).

When they select an option, I am wanting to hide all of the sections in the UITableView expect, obviously, the one section with the title of the selected option.

I was wondering if you could loop through all of the sections, look at its title, and if it didnt match the selection, hide it? It might be worthwhile to note there will never be anymore than 10 sections with a few cells each, so I don't know if [table updateTable] or [table reloadData] is better.

My attempt:

```
//Filter out the notes that should display
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
//self.notesTable.dataSource = [myArrayOfDictionaries objectAtIndex:row]; 
//[self.notesTable reloadData]; this did not work

for (int section = 0; section < [notesTable numberOfSections]; section++){
    //find sections that don't match pickerview selection
    NSLog@("%@",[notesTable headerViewForSection:row);//return null?

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post code for your `UITableView.delegate` and `UITableView.dataSource` methods?

You want to do something like this:

- Maintain a `@property` pointing to allData and maintain another `@property` pointing to currentData
- User picks a section
- You grab the sectionData out of allData, set this sectionData as your currentData
- Call `reloadData` on the `tableView`
- Make sure your `delegate` and `dataSource` methods reference the `currentData` `@property`

It looks like the reason that this did not work for you above is because you are setting the `UITableView`'s `dataSource = currentData`, which is incorrect. `DataSource` should always be set to the class that you set as conforming to this protocol (probably your `UIViewController`).