# Clean approach for refreshing UITableView data from datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c

Somewhat related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687355/filter-entire-sections-of-uitableview-according-to-section-header). So, I have two NSMutableDictionaries. DictA is the original data, while DictB will be the data that the UITableVIew gets the data from. If the user filters by something, I can remove all the objects in DictB that shouldn't be displayed, and then call [table reloadData] and that works fine, achieved like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary filterSelection = [DictA objectForKey:what the user picked];
[dictB removeAllObjects];
dictB = filterSelection;
[table reloadData];
```

This will make the UITableView show only what the user filtered by.

**Here is where the issues begin:**

- How do I "refresh" all the data back into DictB so the user can make a new selection? i.e. DictB = DictA (*obviously* that won't work due to reference types, just put it there to show that I need all the data back to filter over once more). This won't work in any event, because removing all objects from dictB removes everything from dictA because they are referencing the same objects in memory.

Any suggestions welcome, I feel I have the right idea, just lost on the execution.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an objectAtIndex method, so DictA can't be a dictionary, it must be an array (or mutable array).

Comment: You are correct, I was typing up my pseudocode a bit too quickly. I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call

```
[dictB addEntriesFromDictionary:dictA];
```

and that should copy everything from `dictA` into `dictB`. Now you may have to clear out `dictB` before doing so, but it should work

[NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Something a simple as `dictB = [dictA copy];` may also work. Not sure though if that has problems with retain counts, or anything like that.

Comment: Wow that works, I thought it would much more work. Is addEntriesFromDictionary making copies of the objects?

Comment: I am not too sure if it is. Probably not, but as long as your retain count on the object is high enough it will not disappear, and because dictA still has reference to the object though you may have removed it from dictB, you should be fine.

Comment: so looking at the documentation quickly, it seems that the keys for the dictionary are copied into the new dictionary, but the object itself is not, it is just told to increment the retain count. [addEntriesFromDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/addEntriesFromDictionary:)

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how your data models are set up, but generally, there is no need to have two pointers to the same object in the memory. For example:

```
dictB = dictA;
```

The above just creates a reference, and is probably what you are doing.

```
dictB = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictA];
```

This creates a copy of the data which you can manage separately from the original object.

There are plenty of other ways to handle this, i suggest you look into the documentation of `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` for other possibilities.